# How to add a multi-line text for a button using template literals

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxtjs

I want to set a button's text using javascript in my nuxtjs app. The text should be multi-line with the second line a value coming from somewhere else. This is the code I have written but it doesn't work:

```
data(){
  return{
    text: null,
    otherValue: "this is line two"
  }
},
methods:{
  setText(){
    this.text = `this is line one \n `${this.otherValue}`
  }
},
mounted(){
  this.setText()
}
```

What it does is it puts as many characters as it can into the first line and then goes to the second line if there is no space. How can I fix it?

P.S this is the CSS for my button:

```
  background-color: #85c53a;
  border: solid 0px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
```

Comment: Have you tried `<br>` instead of `\n`?

Answer (score 0):

The line break dosen't work as it should in the button for text. You can use `br` or `p` tag and use `v-html` binding to display it.

Here is the example:

```
setText(){
  this.text = `this is line one <br />${this.otherValue}`
}
```

In Template:

```
<button class="btn" v-html="text"></button>
```

**Tip**: remove the height from button style and use display-inline block to adapt the height based on context.

```
.btn{
    background-color: #85c53a;
    border: solid 0px;
    width: 190px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
```